# Android app submit throws Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, android, spring, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to app world and started building Android app using phonegap for my already available service which serves for my web users. i have my services build on java, spring mvc, and my controllers are capable of receiving json objects.

so kept that in mind. i have created basic login page with login button and i was trying to hit my backend services. i have below code

```
$('#login_btn').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/myweb/user/signin",
        type: "post",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        data: "userName=" + $("#username_txt").val() + '&password=' + $("#password_txt").val(),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("ok");
        },
        error : function(data){
            alert("not ok");
        }

});
```

my controller method accepts POST request, when i hit login button, i see my service giving me error as

> HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not
>   supported

and my error block getting executed.i dont what i am doing wrong here, thanks for your answers

EDIT-

my server side controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelMap loginUser(@RequestParam(value = "userName") String userName, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

Comment: Change type to "POST"

Comment: Can you post you server side code as well

Comment: added server side controller code